# Select * into #tempTable from exec Command shows an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am executing the string that contains the below code

```
DECLARE @BadgeNo NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @BadgeNo='8107';

SELECT * INTO #Testing 
   EXEC spNotification 'Param1','Param2','Param3','Param4';

EXEC  spSqlTmpTblToHtmlTbl 'tempdb..#Testing'
```

I just want the result in html format. So I am executing `spnotification` to get the results.

The `spSqlTmpTblToHtmlTbl` converts the temp table to table format. But here is an issue that I can't create a temp table from `spNotification` result. I know

```
select * into
```

command won't work with the `exec` command. So how can I achieve this?

Comment: change your spNotification to a table value function and then use it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure

Comment: I already have to Stored Procedure and we are trying to use that stored procedure globally. Incase if we have to make any modification in the logic we have to alter the SP alone. Also function takes much time to compile and execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this":

```
CREATE TABLE #Testing 
(
   COLUMN1 INT,
   COLUMN2 INT
)

INSERT INTO #Testing 
Exec spNotification 'Param1','Param2','Param3','Param4';
```

Also check [How to SELECT * INTO [temp table] FROM [stored procedure]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Or you may try with OPENQUERY:

```
SELECT  *
INTO    #Testing 
FROM    OPENQUERY(YOURSERVERNAME, 'Exec spNotification 'Param1','Param2','Param3','Param4'')
```

Comment: spnotification will produce dynamic data.In our environment openQuery has been restricted!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Testing TABLE 
  ( 
     COLUMN1 INT, 
     COLUMN2 INT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @Testing 
            (COLUMN1, 
             COLUMN2) 
EXEC SPNOTIFICATION 
  'Param1', 
  'Param2', 
  'Param3', 
  'Param4';
```